# What's the difference between "much of" and much of "a/an"?

Tags: articles

What's the difference between "much of" and much of "a/an"?

For example:

> Not much of India is barren.
>
> You can’t see much of a country in a week.

I would like to know the difference(s) between "much of" and "much of a/an", if there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **India** is a proper noun, that's why we can't use the indefinite [article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles) **a/an** before it (with some very rare exceptions).

The word **country** is a singular countable noun, that's why we must use either an indefinite or definite article before it: either **a/an** or **the**.